# how to monitor RDS space used?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am using RDS for mysqlDB with storage of 60 GB , There are many databases and total size is of databases are 20 GB . But at present RDS is showing just 10 GB free space .. I am unable to check why there is a gap of 30GB and how do i clear occupied space ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take this image as a reference:
[image]

In your RDS panel you will find that summary part of Memory(RAM), CPU and Storage.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon CloudWatch [provides a `FreeStorageSpace` metric](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/rds-metricscollected.html) but you are not given any further insight into how that disk space is used.

You can perform normal MySQL DBA requests that can provide more insight (eg [Get the database size, free space and last update](http://mysqladministrators.blogspot.com.au/2012/02/get-database-size.html)) but MySQL is a fully-managed database so you will have very little control over how disk space is managed and allocated.

Comment: Free storage space isn't the same as storage used.  Seems like AWS is intentionally making this difficult to make it harder to determine if space is being wasted and to sell more bits.